# How to get a Appium child element from document when child is different based on phone type (Button/TextView)

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath, appium

I am trying to solve this with `xpath` but I am open to another solution.

On different phones the document is created differently.  Inside the `LinearLayout` the child is a `Button` on Samsung and `TextView` on LG.

I wanted to know if there is a easy way to get one or the other.

I tried to do this using `xpath` to check for the `Button`.  If it exists then its for the `samsung` and click it.  The problem is that `Appium` just hangs trying to find the `Button`.  I figured it would look and move on.

I can setup the code to get the parent and then find by class the child and take the second index but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Is there any way to do the xpath to process the child without specifying its name/type?

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0'][1]")
```

**Here is the current code:**

```
 if (!StringUtility.isEmptyString(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='0']")).getAttribute("name"))) {
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='0']")).click();
 } else { // LG or Other 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']")).click();
 }
```

[image: LG Phone]

[image: Samsung Phone]

**Appium log:**

```
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.Button[@index='0']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.Button[@index='0']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.widget.Button[@index='0'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. "}
> info: [debug] Waited for 10987ms so far
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the xpath dynamically using the Capabilities

```
if(capabilities.getCapability("deviceName")).equals("Samsung")
xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@index='0']"
else
xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

Comment: the problem is that you would have to do that for each device name.  Maybe this will work in the future more devices are used.  The only issue I dont like is that deviceName isnt Samsung or LG its deviceName=LGH820f9798a22.

The other way I thought is capturing the exception when it looks for Button and retrying TextView.